# min-height causes padding to be ignored

Tags: html, css

After adding `min-height` to a div, the child element is flowing outside of the padding. The next element has `height: 100%`, which I think has something to do with it.

```css
html, body { height: 100%;}
.card {height: 100%;}
.card-header {min-height: 50px;}
.card-block {height: 100%;}
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap@4.1.3" data-semver="4.1.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script data-require="bootstrap@4.1.3" data-semver="4.1.3" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
              <div>line 1</div>
              <div>line 2</div>
              <div>line 3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            Some other content
          </div>
        </div>
```

You can see the issue in [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/AGXgDIfaDW7GSayF7ZWH) plunk. If you simply remove the `min-height: 50px` code from the card-header class, you can see that it gets a little bigger. I would like to have a min-height, but still have the padding respected. I really don't understand what's happening here.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 76.0.3809.132

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kmgt is correct in that `card-block` is messing up your sizing. Keep in mind that `height: 100%` is not calculating for the remaining height. Percentage is pretty complicated, but long story short, the most reliable way to use it with respect to the parent container. The interaction between `card-block` and the `min-height: 50px` is what is messing up your styling.

Anyone is more than welcome to chime in, but I personally do not reliably know what is exactly going on. That being said, the solution is `flexbox`. Make the parent `flex` and give `card-block`, the element that needs to occupy the rest of the parent's container size, a `flex-grow: 1`.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.card {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card-header {
  min-height: 50px;
}
.card-block {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: `.card` is already `display: flex` by bootstrap. `flex-grow: 1` is the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `height: 100%;` from `.card`

```
.card {
  /* height: 100%; */
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.card {
  /* height: 100%; */
}

.card-header {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.card-block {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
      <div>line 1</div>
      <div>line 2</div>
      <div>line 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block">
    Some other content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still want that div to extend to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to keep the card height 100%, add `display:block;`

```
.card {
  height: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: You can see in the plunk, if you `add display: block;` to the card, you get a scroll bar, because the card-block extends off the bottom of the page. This similarly causes a lot of problems in the page I'm working on.

Comment: oh, didn't notice, you may hide it with `overflow:hidden`